# How can I display a specific child component inside a parent component with its own routing in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-components, angular-component-router

I can easily display a child component inside a parent component, but how can I switch the displaying of a child based on a route?

Is it possible to create a routing mechanism like this without using *ngIf's to hide and show the child components?

I have a profile page, ex. ../members/edit

When you first route to the page I want to load up and display the child component

```
<app-profile-menu-items>
```

like this

```html
<app-parent-component class="container">
  <div class="col-2">
    // general info 
  </div>
  <div class="col-10">
    // child component here
    // only want to show 1 child at a time based on some routing
    <app-profile-menu-items></app-profile-menu-items>
  </div>
</app-parent-component>
```

This child component `<app-profile-menu-items>`

has a list of options (links) in it to select from (/member/edit/info, /member/edit/images, etc), which when clicked should display that child component and hide

`<app-profile-menu-items>` // hidden when one below is shown

```
<app-profile-menu-info></app-profile-menu-info>
<app-profile-menu-images></app-profile-menu-images>
<app-profile-menu-location></app-profile-menu-location>
```

Additionally, how would the routing work ex. path: 'edit/info', what would I use for the component?

```
{ path: 'edit', component: MemberEditComponent, resolve: {user: MemberEditResolver}, canDeactivate: [PreventUnsavedChangesGuard]},
```

Comment: You'll need a lazy loaded module that will load the parent component with a router outlet and routes to the different child components.

Comment: Is your app-parent-component getting injected into the template via its selector or is it a routed component?

Comment: Ugur - it's a routed component

Comment: Jean - do you have any examples you can point me too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your parent template should be something like this and it should have routerOutlet:

```
<app-parent-component class="container">
    <div class="col-2">
      // general info 
    </div>
    <div class="col-10">
      // child component here
      // only want to show 1 child at a time based on some routing
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
</app-parent-component>
```

and your routes in routing module:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: '',            //<---- parent component declared here
    component: ParentComponent,
    children: [                          
        {
            path:'child-1',
            component: Child1Component  // <-- Child component 
        },
        {
            path:'child-2',
            component: Child2Component  // <-- Child component 
        },
        {
            path:'child-3',
            component: Child3Component // <-- Child component 
        }
    ]
 }
];
```

Comment: Hi Arashatami. How does it know to load a default component for the child? ex. <app-profile-menu-items>

Comment: Hi , I edit my answer , with empty path and write the correct component for parent as the example I wrote for you routing module load parent then in the template of parent component router outlet load childs.

Answer (score 1):

You can set routes as follows.

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'parent-component',            //<---- parent component declared here
        component: ParentComponent,
        children: [                          
            {
                path:'profile-menu-items',
                component: ProfileMenuItemsComponent  // <-- Child component 
            },
            {
                path:'profile-menu-images',
                component: ProfileMenuImagesComponent  // <-- Child component 
            },
            {
                path:'profile-menu-location',
                component: ProfileMenuLocationComponent // <-- Child component 
            }
        ]
     }
  ];
```

Comment: Kavinda - thanks, what about the html? How do I construct the html code?

Comment: Huh! I don't understand your comment.

Comment: This way is correct  <div class="col-10">
    // child component here
    // only want to show 1 child at a time based on some routing
    <app-profile-menu-items></app-profile-menu-items>
  </div>

Comment: are you saying that Angular will hide/show automatically based on what I've routed too?